# Dictate of Erebos and Bestowed creatures

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-bestow

Bestow is a mechanic with the following reminder text:

> (*If you cast this card for its bestow cost, it’s an Aura spell with enchant creature. It becomes a creature again if it's not attached to a creature.*)

[Dictate of Erebos](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Dictate%20of%20Erebos) has the following effect:

> Whenever a creature you control dies, each opponent sacrifices a creature.

Consider the following case:

- My opponent controls a Dictate of Erebos
- I control a Creature which has, as an Aura attached to it, a card with Bestow (in my case, an [Underworld Coinsmith](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Underworld%20Coinsmith) with [Hopeful Eidolon](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Hopeful%20Eidolon) as an Aura)
- I control a single other creature, which I want to avoid sacrificing (in my case, a [Doomwake Giant](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Doomwake%20Giant))
- A single effect kills two of my opponent’s creatures (in my case, the Doomwake Giant’s Constellation effect triggered while he had two 1/1s)
- I choose, as my first sacrifice, the Creature enchanted with the Bestowed card (in my case, the Underworld Coinsmith above)

In this situation, does the Bestowed card (e.g. the Hopeful Eidolon above) revert to being a Creature in time for me to choose it as the next sacrifice?

Or does it only revert to being a Creature after all triggered instances of Dictate of Erebos have resolved, forcing me to sacrifice the creature I want to save (e.g. the Doomwake Giant above)?

Comment: You can use `[mtg:Card Name]` to tag cards. I don't recommend it for cards with an apostrophe in the name.

Comment: For cards with an apostrophe in the name, you can tag it by just leaving out the apostrophe (and leave out the s after the apostrophe if there is one).

Comment: @GendoIkari what about weird cases where the apostrophe is just part of the name, not a possessive, and more significant parts come after it?

Comment: @KRyan I don't know if there's a solution to that, currently.

Comment: Well, there's not a *lazy* solution. You can always search for the card on the [Gatherer](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Default.aspx) and link it yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may sacrifice [Underworld Coinsmith](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Underworld%20Coinsmith), and then you may sacrifice [Hopeful Eidolon](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Hopeful%20Eidolon).

Whenever a creature dies, all of its enchantment(s) **become unattached**. Normally, they would be sent straight to the graveyard as a state based action. However, enchantments with Bestow immediately become a creature instead due to rule [CR](http://media.wizards.com/2014/downloads/MagicCompRules_20140926.pdf) 702.102a. The commonly used slang terminology for this action is "falls off".

Triggers from [Dictate of Erebos](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Dictate%20of%20Erebos) resolve one at a time. If you sacrifice Underworld Coinsmith to the first trigger, then Hopeful Eidolon immediately "falls off" and is ready to be sacrificed to the second trigger.

> 702.102a If you chose to pay this spell’s bestow cost, it becomes an Aura enchantment and gains enchant creature. These effects last until the permanent this spell becomes **becomes unattached**.

Comment: I just want to point out that that Comprehensive Rules link is actually out of date. It doesn't have the rules for Khans of Tarkir. I would suggest instead linking to [MTG Salvation](http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/Comprehensive_Rules), which is completely up to date. Specifically, I'd suggest linking to [this page](http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/Bestow).

Comment: The rules you linked *also* don't have the Magic 2015 rules changes.

Comment: Alternatively, [this page](http://magic.wizards.com/en/gameinfo/gameplay/formats/comprehensiverules) links to the most up to date official rule book.

Comment: Minor improvement: Triggers from Dictate of Erebos resolve one at a time => Abilities on the stack (including the triggered ability from Dictate of Erebos) resolve one at a time

Comment: @murgtroid99 Thanks. I fixed the link, and I double checked that the rule number was still the same. I hadn't seen the new page until you pointed it out.

Comment: @Rainbolt That's not surprising. I have not yet found a Google search that results in a link to that page. Luckily, there hasn't been a major change in rule numbers since M14.

Answer (score 2):

Dictate of Erebos' effect goes onto the stack for each instance it was triggered. The Hopeful Eidolon becomes a creature as soon as the creature it's attached to is removed from the battlefield so it will be a creature before the second Erebos trigger resolves, so you may sacrifice it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer; I've accepted the other one because rules quotes, but I did upvote both. Also, is your nick a reference to *Illusion of Gaia*? Cuz that's awesome.

Comment: Yeah, I wrote this from memory and went to add the reference after the fact, but Rainbolt beat me to it.

Comment: @KRyan I just saw the edit to your comment, and yes it is a reference to _Illusion of Gaia_. You win some sort of award for being the 3rd person to notice it (or notice it and then say something) in the 10+ years I've used the moniker as my online alias.